# How to get Github latest commit url using cli with respect to current branch

Tags: git, powershell, github, command-line-interface

How to get Github latest commit url using cli?
example output: https://github.com/my_user/my_repo/commit/0904dcc315ec80d024440dda5208ebf1d7edbcb3

The closest thing I found is `git rev-parse HEAD` which returns the latest commit but doesn't return the complete github url.

I use `powershell` (pwsh) as terminal.

I also have [Github CLI](https://cli.github.com/) installed along with `git`.

Comment: Could you clarify: What do you mean by 'get last commit'? Do you want to check out the latest commit of a branch? Rollback your working copy to the last commit? Revert a commit you already made to a previous one?

Comment: `https://api.github.com/repos/USER/REPONAME/commits` might help you.

Comment: @A-Tech nope, just want to get the latest commit url with respect to current branch using cli. so, that I can directly click it and open in browser or share the link with colleagues.

Comment: @dan1st that's not what I'm looking for. I'm hoping for some cli command to get the url of latest commit. for example `git rev-parse HEAD` returns the last commit but doesn't return the complete github url

Comment: I dont know of any way to get the complete URL, but you can just add the ID you get from `git rev-parse HEAD` to _https://github.com/my_user/my_repo/commit/_ and you'd have essentially what you want. You could even write a little bash/sh script to automatically add the two strings together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using PowerShell, just insert that commit hash into your URL:

```
"https://github.com/my_user/my_repo/commit/$(git rev-parse HEAD)"
```

To make it even more flexible, you can excute the following command:

```
"$($(git config --get remote.origin.url) -ireplace '\.git$', '')/commit/$(git rev-parse HEAD)"
```

This should work for all repositories that have been cloned from [github](https://github.com/), not only your specific one.

You can write this into a function and [add it to your profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles), to get the URL quicker/easier:

```
function Get-GitUrl {
    return "$($(git config --get remote.origin.url) -ireplace '\.git$', '')/commit/$(git rev-parse HEAD)"
}
```

Comment: Note that this requires cloning the repository beforehand and it won't point to the newest/current commit if the user checked out something else.

Comment: As the asker is OK with the commit hash from `git rev-parse HEAD`, this should be fine. I agree that, for different needs, an even more general approach might be needed.

Answer (score 4):

This works out of the box with the Github CLI:

```
gh browse  -c -n
```

will display the GitHub url of the latest commit on the current branch.

Or

```
gh browse -c
```

will open the browser at that url.

Reference: https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_browse

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this. Since it's a tree view, not a commits view - it's difficult to see previous and later commits.

Comment: Good point - my solution returns `https://github.com/USER/REPO/tree/COMMIT_SHA`  rather than `https://github.com/USER/REPO/commit/COMMIT_SHA`.

Can improve it by replacing `-c` with `$(git rev-parse HEAD)`. So full command for url is `gh browse  $(git rev-parse HEAD) -n`. Surprised there isn't a way to do this using github cli only.

Comment: Nice @MDJ !. tl;dr:
`gh browse $(git rev-parse HEAD) -n`

Answer (score 0):

echo "${$(git config --get remote.origin.url)/.git/}/commit/$(git rev-parse HEAD)"