# Get Github latest commit url - zsh shell

Tags: git, github, zsh

How to get Github latest commit url using cli in `zsh`?
example output: https://github.com/my_user/my_repo/commit/0904dcc315ec80d024440dda5208ebf1d7edbcb3

> This is related to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69099079/how-to-get-github-latest-commit-url-using-cli-with-respect-to-current-branch) I asked sometime back for Windows `powershell` but now I've switched to Mac and looking for a similar command for `zsh` shell. The command mentioned in the answer is of course not compatible with zsh.

Comment: I assume something like this is what you are after: `git log -1 --format='https://github.com/my_user/my_repo/commit/%H'` `my_user` and `my_repo` can possible be extracted from `git remote -v`

Comment: You can use `sed` remove `.git` from the output of `git config --get remote.origin.url` which is also done in your linked question. And as you have already discovered, you can get a commit from `git rev-parse HEAD` gluing it together should be trivial, when you understand how command substitutions and string concatenation works.